# Install Flatpak apps on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, flatpak

I just installed Flatpak recently but after installing it, I can't find the apps in Ubuntu Software. I installed the Flatpak plugin for Ubuntu Software Center and I can't find any apps.

Actually, I found the flatpak sourced apps, but it signed me out of Ubuntu One, so I signed back in and then it was gone. I can't find the flatpak sourced apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [install Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) support using command line and install an available application from its main public repository, called [Flathub](https://flathub.org/).

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Add Flathub as a source repository.

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

You can search and install any Flatpak software. (For example Firefox).

```
flatpak search firefox

flatpak install flathub org.mozilla.firefox
```

Here `org.mozilla.firefox` is Application ID of Firefox in [Flathub](https://flathub.org/).

You can also install the application by downloading `.flatpakref` files.

On Flathub, by clicking on `Install` button will download `.flatpakref` file for application or you can also install application it by copying its  URL. For example [Firefox](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.firefox).

```
flatpak install <Path of .flatpakref file you downloaded from flathub>

flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.mozilla.firefox.flatpakref
```

Comment: already did that

Comment: I have an issue where I try to `flatpak install ./Downloads/xxxx` but it doesn't autocomplete, and doesn't find the file if I manually type the path...

Answer (score 7):

The pre-installed software store application in Ubuntu 20.04 is a [snap application](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started) (Snap Store) (source: [OMG! Ubuntu article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/ubuntu-snap-store-transition)). It doesn't seem to support the flatpak plugin.

As a workaround you can install the traditional (GNOME) Software application by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

You also need to install the `gnome-software-plugin-flatpak` (which you have already installed apparently).

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak

flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Additionally, you may remove the pre-installed Snap Store by

```
snap remove snap-store
```

Comment: This resolves "Failed to install file: not supported" when you try to open a `.flatpakref` in the software center (default action (I am honestly surprised why doesn't even suggest to install this plugin...". (software center app restart was needed). I would not remove the snap store though... One can have both.

Comment: to be super clear: `sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak` was enough to start downloading and installing apps from https://flathub.org/ through GUI :-)